# Inequality solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the solution to $|x-2|+2x \le 16$

Upon calculating it, I got two inequalities:
$$x \le 6$$
$$x \le 14$$

What is the range supposed to be? I am confused.  Did I calculate the question correctly? I keep getting the same inequalities, but I can't figure out the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x-2 \geq 0 \iff x \geq 2$, we have
$$\begin{array}{rcl}|x-2|+2x\leq 16 
&\iff &\left\{\begin{array}{l l}x-2+2x \leq 16 &\text{if } x\geq 2\\ 2-x + 2x \leq 16 & \text{if } x\leq 2\end{array}\right. \\ &\iff &\left\{\begin{array}{l l}3x \leq 18 & \text{if }x\geq 2\\ x \leq 14 & \text{if }x\leq 2\end{array}\right. \\ &\iff &\left\{\begin{array}{l l}x \leq 6 & \text{if }x\geq 2\\ x \leq 14 &\text{if } x\leq 2\end{array}\right. \\&\iff &\left\{\begin{array}{l}x\in [2,6] \\ x \in (-\infty,2]\end{array}\right.\\ & \iff & x \in (-\infty,6] \end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases:

1)$x \geq 2$, then we have:

$x-2+2x  \leq 16$, so $x \leq 6$, then for $x \in [2,6]$ we have $|x-2|+2x \leq 16$, for $x >6$ is $|x-2|+2x > 16$

2)$x < 2$, then:

$|x-2|+2x=2-x+2x=2+x \leq 16$, so it's equal $x \leq 14$, so for $x <2$ also $|x-2|+2x \leq 16$, so finally solution is $x \leq 6$

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just have to plug in a number and sea if it works. Try $x = 7$. Then $|x - 2| + 2x = 7 - 2 + 2 \times 7 = 19$, so that would have told you $x \leq 14$ is wrong and thus you made a mistake somehwere.

If $x \geq 2$, then left-hand side of teh inequality can be rewritten as $3x - 2$. Then $3x - 2 \leq 16$ has the solution $x \leq 6$.

If $x < 2$, then left-hand side of teh inequality can be rewritten as $(-1)x - 2 + 2x = x - 2$ and therefour any $x < 2$ will work. so I have no idea where you got $x \leq 14$ fromm.

p.s. just wondring: must $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ or can $x \in \mathbb{R}$?